# How to detect a capacitor installation

Tags: capacitor, analog, connector, msp430, detection

The circuit I'm designing uses external capacitor to measure its ESR. I use MSP430 as a controller, capacitance of the external capacitor can vary between 100n and 10uF. The problem is I should somehow detect the moment when someone installs the external capacitor, so the MSP would turn off the sleep mode and start measuring.

It came to my mind that I can use a comparator for that. For ex, to power the external capacitor with DC (from DAC) and to detect voltage raise, but isn't the rise too small to detect? I got 500uV while modelling.

I heard there are some special connectors that are able to detect installation and switch the internal relay, but i wasn't able to find ones.

Comment: Why not measure all the time? Why do you need to go into sleep mode? If you do need to sleep, why not wake once every second and measure?

Comment: @Andyaka Sleep mode is used to reduce power consumption. One of the requirement to the circuit

Comment: Basically wake up once a second. read the ADC, go to sleep again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  a circuit like this the cap should be discharged on insertion which will pull down the input to the buffer creating a wake up signal.

If the resistor will interfere with your measurement you can compensate for its presence in the software.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzQV5Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A CMOS buffer could be used, which will draw essentially no current. Remember to tie any unused inputs to a rail. It is imperative that the capacitor be discharged before inserting - many (cheaper, home-made) capacitance meters have been destroyed by caps with even 4V charge on them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ZIF socket for the capacitor connection and put a tactile button under the lever, or 90 degree tactile button at the end of the sled.